# Get object array in blender python script

Tags: python, blender, bpy

I am creating my simple game engine with C++ and OpenGL ES3, so I am not a python or blender developer I just use blender for creating low poly models now I wanna using blender as a levels editor so after some researches I created a simple exporter which export the scene to a XML file and it worked fine, [My post in blender exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93875/export-scene-for-my-own-game-engine/93893#93893).
I am using instances in my engine so I wanna create array of the same object in blender and export the matrix and count so if I create an array modifier how could I get data for the instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
create link copy of the object then iterate through `bpy.data.meshes` then found the mesh owner using this script

```
mesh_owners = {}
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
if ob.type == 'MESH':
    mesh_owners.setdefault(ob.data, []).append(ob)
```

Thanks for [How to access mesh data of an object in a script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/how-to-access-mesh-data-of-an-object-in-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution using face instancing.
I use it for nondestructive, yet performacne effective jobs.

```
import bpy
# get the object
mon = bpy.context.active_object
# create the plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=mon.dimensions[0], enter_editmode=False, align = 'WORLD', location=(mon.location))
plan= bpy.context.active_object
plan.dimensions[1] = mon.dimensions[1]
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)
plan.name = mon.name+'_C'
# parent the objects and set up
mon.parent = plan
mon.location = (0,0,0)
plan.instance_type = 'FACES'
plan.show_instancer_for_render = False
plan.show_instancer_for_viewport = False
# add Array modifiers
FC = plan.modifiers.new(type='ARRAY', name='FaceCount')
FC.count = 5
DC = plan.modifiers.new(type='ARRAY', name='DepthCount')
DC.relative_offset_displace[0]= 0
DC.relative_offset_displace[1]= 1
DC.count = 5
HC = plan.modifiers.new(type='ARRAY', name='HeightCount')
HC.use_relative_offset = False
HC.use_constant_offset = True
HC.constant_offset_displace[0]=0
HC.constant_offset_displace[2]=mon.dimensions[2]
HC.count = 1
```

This is literally the first time me using python in blender. So possibly there are better ways to do it.